# Dynamic columns when pivoting

Tags: sql, pivot

I have a table of equipment, a table of customers and a sparse table of equipment and customers. I want to produce a query that returns a 1 if the equipment/Customer table record exists and a 0 if it doesn't for each customer. There are only a small number of customers in this problem, so what I want back should look like this:

```
EquipmentID   Cust1   Cust2   Cust3
-----------   -----   -----   -----
       1234       1       0       1
       1357       0       1       0
       2234       1       0       0
```

I can use a `cross join` to get a master list of possible records, but that returns the information in rows. I want to see it in columns, but the `PIVOT` keyword requires that I name the columns first. What I need is for the column names (`Cust1`, `Cust2`...) to be dynamic.

Comment: You would probably be better off handling that kind of a display transformation in the front end if possible.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to do that, then you have to create the query string dynamically and then pass it to the [`sp_execute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) stored procedure.  AFAIK, there isn't a way to do it without constructing the query string dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reporting tool handy use your current query and make a "martix", "cross-tab", or "pivot table" report.

Comment: I am trying to do this within a web page. What I want to see is the SQL code to accomplish this.

Comment: SQL is still not the place do this.  Your "reporting tool" is now your web language.  You have the flexibility with in your language to traverse your recordset in a way to get what you want.  Your framework may even have a some type of pivot or transpose class to do it for you.