# Display only values that are greater than one in an sql query that uses pivot tables in a CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that produces a number of columns, most of them containing 0.  I want to only display the columns that have a value > 0.  This query is in a CTE, and pivoted so as to produce one row.  My query is as follows:

```sql
   select [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15]

from (select inv.statusreason

from invBillTBL inv WITH (NOLOCK)
     INNER JOIN CarrierTBL car WITH (NOLOCK) On inv.Carrier_Key = Car.Carrier_Key

where inv.ClientLoc_Key IN (
           select ClientLoc_key from clientloctbl WITH (NOLOCK)
           where Client_Key = 286)
    and inv.invEnteredDate >= '2013-11-08' and inv.invEnteredDate < '2013-11-14'
    and car.SCAC = 'DNZA'
    and inv.statusreason <> '' ) a

pivot
(count(statusreason)  
for statusreason in ( [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15])) p `
```

The output looks like this (shortened version): [image]
The full row goes out to the end of the statusreasons listed above.

[image]

Most of the columns have 0 in the field (along with their count).  I want to only display the columns with counts > 0.  This question has been difficult to formulate, so if I have missed something or left something out, please let me know.  Thanks in advance for any assistance anyone can provide.

Comment: SQL is *not* a good tool for producing output with a variable number of columns.  It can be done, but you will usually be much better off doing it in your application layer.  What are you using for reporting?

Comment: SSRS eventually.  I have gotten this far in SSMS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic columns when pivoting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/706290/dynamic-columns-when-pivoting)

Comment: You essentially want dynamic pivoted columns. This is not possible with a single query. You first need a pass to decide which columns you need, then generate and run dynamic SQL. Search for "pivot dynamic" - most of the chosen answers will fit your case as well.

Comment: Well asked. Unfortunately, I don't think this is possible, as others have already said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dump your inner query into a temp table (I don't have your data, so I faked it)

```
CREATE TABLE #t (statusreason int);
INSERT #t VALUES
(5),(5),(5),(5),(5),
(8),(8),(8),
(12),(12),(12),(12),(12),(12),
(12),(12),(12),(12),(12),(12);
```

Create a comma-separated list of columns, using QUOTENAME() to defend against injection

```
DECLARE @cols nvarchar(max);

SELECT @cols = COALESCE(@cols+',','')+QUOTENAME(LTRIM(STR([statusreason])))
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [statusreason] FROM #t) t;
```

Use the list of columns to build a dynamic query

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

SET @sql = 'SELECT '+@cols+' FROM #t PIVOT(COUNT([statusreason]) FOR [statusreason] IN ('+@cols+')) p';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```